# EM_FINDTEXTEX not working

Tags: find, richedit

I'm working on Visual Studio 2008 in a rich edit version `RichEdit50W` into a ATL CAxDialogImpl and I'm trying to search for text. Project properties characters coding is multibyte.

Here is my code:

```
FINDTEXTEX stFindPalError;
CHARRANGE RangeError;
int outret;

SendMessage(hWndRichEdit, EM_GETSEL, 0, (LPARAM)&RangeError);

stFindPalError.chrg.cpMin = RangeError.cpMin;
stFindPalError.chrg.cpMax = RangeError.cpMax;
stFindPalError.lpstrText = _T("ss");

outret = SendMessage(hWndRichEdit, EM_FINDTEXTEX, (WPARAM)FR_DOWN, (LPARAM)&stFindPalError);
```

This seems to work with single character strings `(_T("s"))`, with a little strange return values, but with multiple character strings I receive always `-1`.

I've tried a lot of variations with selection position and `WPARAM` parameters but always I receive `-1` with multiple character string search.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you're being tripped up by a Unicode / ANSI mis-match between the message and its associated structure. Not entirely surpringly, Microsoft have made this about as confusing as possible. Looking at the definitions of the messages in the SDK, we have:

```
#define EM_FINDTEXTEX           (WM_USER + 79)
#define EM_FINDTEXTEXW          (WM_USER + 124)
```

Reading the MSDN pages, EM_FINDTEXTEX is for ANSI strings, and EM_FINDTEXTEXW is for Unicode strings.

But when you look at the definition of the associated structure, there's an ANSI form (FINDTEXTEXA) and a Unicode form (FINDTEXTEXW), with

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define FINDTEXTEX  FINDTEXTEXW
#else
#define FINDTEXTEX  FINDTEXTEXA
#endif // UNICODE
```

So the "trailing-A"/"trailing-W" rules for ANSI and Unicode are different between the structure and the message itself. Urgh.

Looking at your code, I'm going to guess that the project is set to compile as Unicode. That means that your

```
   FINDTEXTEX stFindPalError;
```

will compile as a "FINDTEXTEXW" structure, but you're using the EM_FINDTEXTEX message, which is only for ANSI strings. This would explain why it works for one character strings, but not anything else.

To fix, change EM_FINDTEXTEX to EM_FINDTEXTEXW, and if that works mutter darkly about the quality of the RichEdit headers ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks DavidK,

My project as I said: 'properties characters coding is multibyte' is compiled as no UNICODE. So it is expected that 'FINDTEXTEX stFindPalError' was translated to 'FINDTEXTEXA stFindPalError' and it should work with EM_FINDTEXTEX. After your answer I've tried a lot of different possibilities and I've found that this one works:

```
FINDTEXTEXW stFindPalError;

...

LPCWSTR str = L"ss";
...
stFindPalError.lpstrText = str;
...
outret = SendMessage(hWndRichEdit, EM_FINDTEXTEX, (WPARAM)FR_DOWN, (LPARAM)&stFindPalError);
```

Why this works?? I don't Know. May be someone could explain why.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug of the ANSI EM_FINDTEXTEX message.He need an UNICODE string to search in an ANSI text.I have try recently to change a older version of richedit for the RichEdit50W working in ANSI,and all searchs was blocked by EM_FINTEXTEX.
After many useless verifies,The code was working with others versions of richedit,I have try to pass the chain .lpstrText as UNICODE and this had worked.
Must be not the only problem than the RichEdit50W has.

Comment: Seems like you two worked together on this. Please show the corrected code in your answer.